# Using WooCommerce and Select2 to create searchable drop down list

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-select2

I've enabled select2 on my billing form (creating using snippets custom form fields)
The select box shows only the first value, no drop down values no searchable values , all I get is no results found.

Form code:

```
        $fields['billing_complex_address_test'] = array(
        'label' => __('Complex Address Test', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('E.g Yellow Tail Road', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required' => false, // if field is required or not
        'clear' => false, // add clear or not
        'type' => 'select', // add field type
        'options' => array(
        '0' => __('Select your complex'),
                         'ansaarestate'=> 'Ansaar Estate',
                         'bangladeshheights'=> 'Bangladesh Heights',
                        'celticmanor'=> 'Celtic Manor',
                        'chantelplace'=> 'Chantel Place',
    ),
        'class' => array('my-custom-class') ,// add class name
         'priority' => 8,
    );
```

My jQuery code

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery(".my-custom-class").select2();
    });
```

Please help me here

Answer (score 0):

ChangedjQuery class to just be `select` worked